# Is there any workaround to build unity applications using named mutex?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mutex

Does anybody know a way to use named Mutex in a unity3d application built for Windows? It seems like this is commonly not supported for Windows builds but in editor it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for asking this question and I can promise that I was searching for an answer for a while, but now I came across the solution by random. You simply have to switch to Scripting Backend "Mono" and API Compatibility-Level ".NET 4.X" in Player Settings to get access to named Mutex. Thanks for anyone who wanted to help!

Comment: what Unity version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your Reply! I am using 2019.4.7 LTS. As I figured out with .NET 2.0 or IL2CPP named Mutexes are not supported in PC build.